# Redirect all requests for a directory to a specific page and create new URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have some language specific directories that don't have any content now, but will get traffic from an external application. So I need to redirect all page request to a specific page that is in the appropriate language that will have some messaging and a link to the equivalent EN page. For example:`http://example.com/DE/somepage.html` (or any other file path containing the /DE/ directory) should go to `http://example.com/DE/temppage.html` I have tried dozens of .htaccess commands with no luck, but this looks right to me but doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^DE/(.+) DE/temppage.html [L,R]
```

**THIS WORKS FOR ME NOW**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/HGTemp.php$ [NC]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
     RewriteRule .* /dir/dir/dir/DE/HGTemp.php [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Because the file paths are the same regardless of directory, I want to take the **requested** URL `http://example.com/DE/somepage.html`, grab the file path and put it in a working url that is the English version IE `http://example.com/EN/somepage.html`. I am trying to do it with PHP, storing the requested URL in a session, take that file path and add it to the correct directory path.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    var extension = $path_parts['extension']; //not correct but the idea is
    echo 'http://example.com/EN/' . $extension . '.com; //not correct but the idea is
?>
```

any ideas on the most efficient way to accomplish these 2 tasks?

**Here is working solution**

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$my_var = 'en-us';
$temp = explode( '/'  , $url );
$temp[6] = $my_var;
$url = implode( '/' , $temp );
$url = str_replace("Page.php", "", $url);
```

Comment: Why do you want to redirect twice? Why not just redirect all traffic to `DE` to the `EN` version to begin with instead of that temppage?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I want to redirect all DE traffic to a page in DE that is in German with messaging, and in that messaging display a link that is the EN version of the page they requested. All file paths are in English

Comment: So what is wrong with the rule? You said it doesn't work. You mean it doesn't redirect at all?

Comment: It just goes to a generic 404 page, not the temp page in the command

Comment: Problem one is fixed

Comment: What do you have 3 sub directories /dir/dir/dir? If you don't provide your exact problem it's difficult for someone to help. Are all the paths like that?

Comment: What will be the exact english equivalent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95460/discussion-between-dirty-bird-design-and-panama-jack).

Comment: the file path IE /FooPage.php will be /FooPage.php in all languages